# How to get stdout and stderr from single Jenkins Pipeline parallel blocks?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a `parallel` block into my Jenkinsfile to execute concurrently some tests, but all the outputs are getting mixed up.

This is an extract of my Jenkinsfile, as an example:

```
// do some IT against different databases
stage name: 'IT'

parallel (
    mysqlIT: {
        node {
            executeMysqlIT()
        }
    },
    oracleIT: {
        node {
            executeOracleIT()
        }
    }
)
```

Please note that, as suggested [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/docs/BEST_PRACTICES.md) I'm running a new `node` within each `parallel`, so they get properly parallelized and each of them gets its own workspace.

What should I do to have Jenkins show me separated outputs for the `parallel` blocks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the build page of your job there is a link "Pipeline steps" on the left. There in the tree-like structure you can find all the steps that your job has run including parallel ones. You can go inside of every step and access its console log using the link on the left. Alternatively you can use a "terminal" icon on the right in the same row.

Click it and you will see the console log which solely produced within that step without any intermixing with other steps running simultaneously. If a step or several parallel steps are still in progress their logs will be dynamically updated on each of their console log pages.

Comment: Wow that's hard to reach! Anyway this was exactly what I was looking for. Do you know any way to add one particular step output directly to the job's left bar?

Comment: I am afraid no. Each step is assigned with a sequential ID as the job runs.  If you don't modify its script often you can add the direct link to the step into the job's description (using the build permalinks) or into the build description by assigning `currentBuild.description` property,

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58050883/8380249 provides a way to get logs from parallel blocks

- either as a string in the pipeline code
- or saved as an artifact of the run

the library used there also provides accessors to the internal ids which I think could be used to generate links to "pipeline steps" files