# Logs of parallel task are disordered

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline

I run several tasks parallel but their logs were printed parallel.
It's hard to understand.

**groovy dsl:**

```
parallel (
  "stream1": { 
    node { ... }
  },
  "stream2": { 
    node("remote") { ... }
  }
)
```

**logs**:

```
[stream1] [workspace] Running shell script 1
[stream2] [workspace] Running shell script 2
[stream2] [workspace] Running shell script 3
[stream1] [workspace] Running shell script 4
```

I want to make these logs readable.
Any ideas how to separate them?

Comment: Make sure that each log entry contains the information you want to sort on.  Sort the log at the end of the job.  Trying to coerce your parallel job to write in order will probably make it as slow as doing the job serially in the first place.  Or, if your hardware supports parallel file operations, have each task make a separate log and combine them after all tasks have finished.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get stdout and stderr from single Jenkins Pipeline parallel blocks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048239/how-to-get-stdout-and-stderr-from-single-jenkins-pipeline-parallel-blocks)

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: I just realised this is answered here: [How to get stdout and stderr from single Jenkins Pipeline parallel blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048239/how-to-get-stdout-and-stderr-from-single-jenkins-pipeline-parallel-blocks/37095547#37095547)

1. Go to your build page e.g. "Jenkins > BUILD_NAME > #163"
2. In the sidepanel click "Pipeline Steps".
3. You should see a layout of all the steps in the pipeline and each can be queries for logs (click the terminal icon) and should have status indicators too.