# Jenkins Pipeline - how to get logs from parallel builds

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible, and if yes: how?, to get the log output for each parallel step separately?

I.e.:

```
def projectBranches = [:]
        for (int i = 0; i < projects.size(); i++) {
            def _i = i
            projectBranches[_i] = {
                someFunction(_i)
            }
        }

        parallel projectBranches
```

Is it now possible to get the log for each of projectBranches[_i]?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37095547/1579623

Comment: @izzekil so if I get it right, there is no "real" way to access the separat log prorammatically?

Comment: oh, I actually did't realize that you need to access them programmatically. I believe it should be achievable via groovy, I'd suggest studying pipeline plugins code to find a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get your nodes by use of Jenkins REST API: job/test/1/api/json?depth=2

Result should contain something like:

```
{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepStartNode","actions":[{},{},{}],"displayName":"Branch: 0","iconColor":"blue","id":"13","parents":["3"],"running":false,"url":"job/test/1/execution/node/13/"},
{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepStartNode","actions":[{},{},{}],"displayName":"Allocate node : Start","iconColor":"blue","id":"23","parents":["13"],"running":false,"url":"job/test/1/execution/node/23/"},
{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepStartNode","actions":[{},{}],"displayName":"Allocate node : Body : Start","iconColor":"blue","id":"33","parents":["23"],"running":false,"url":"job/test/1/execution/node/33/"},
{"_class":"org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.nodes.StepAtomNode","actions":[{},{}],"displayName":"Print Message","iconColor":"blue","id":"37","parents":["33"],"running":false,"url":"job/test/1/execution/node/37/"}
```

So for your case you are interested in the child with type StepAtomNode of your Branch with name given (0-9 for this case). From this you could obtain console output address by simply adding log to the address (like: job/test/1/execution/node/37/log).

Now this is where it gets a bit ugly, you need to parse the html to get the actual log from the

```
<pre class="console-output">log here
</pre>
```

Comment: In the end it was the only practical solution for me, thanks.

Comment: I found that I needed to append `?consoleFull` because some of the logs were large. Also, my log includes timestamps wrapped in `<span>`s, so the parsing was more complex. It's a pity that Jenkins doesn't provide a proper way to do this, since the data is clearly stored in a structured form internally.

Comment: Someone has written a Python tool based on this answer: https://github.com/ssssam/jenkins-parallel-logs

Comment: That's really cool

Comment: Appending `/log` to the node URL gives me only the log of this node, without its children. Do you know a way to get the log of the given node and its children recursively (preferably without having to query the URL of each child node individually)?

Comment: One can use Blue Ocean REST API, but it only shows explicit log messages (such as from `echo` or `sh` steps). It is missing internal log messages, such as from `lock` step. `https://<JenkinsRoot>/blue/rest/organizations/jenkins/pipelines/<MyJob>/runs/<BuildId>/nodes/<NodeId>/log/`

Answer (score 8):

I needed to access logs from within the pipeline code
so I implemented the algorithm proposed by キキジキ (really helpful) with a few adjustments (to add branchName prefix on each line to be able to get the whole log and still figure out which branch corresponds to each line ; and to support nested branches, which I needed) in https://github.com/gdemengin/pipeline-logparser :

- to get logs programmatically

  - to get the full logs with branch prefix (*similar to what `currentBuild.rawBuild.log` returned before version 2.2.5 of workflow-job plugin. but in version 2.26 they got rid of the branch information and I could not find any built-in function with the same information*)
    `String logs = logparser.getLogsWithBranchInfo()`

    > [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
    >   [Pipeline] parallel
    >   [Pipeline] { (Branch: branch1)
    >   [Pipeline] { (Branch: branch2)
    >   [Pipeline] }
    >   [Pipeline] echo
    >   **[branch1]** in branch1
    >   [Pipeline] sleep
    >   **[branch1]** Sleeping for 1 sec
    >   [Pipeline] echo
    >   **[branch2]** in branch2
    >   [Pipeline] sleep
    >   **[branch2]** Sleeping for 1 sec
  - get the logs from 'branch2' only
    `String logsBranch2 = logparser.getLogsWithBranchInfo(filter: ['branch2'])`

    > **[branch2]** in branch2
    >   **[branch2]** Sleeping for 1 sec
- to archive logs (in as $JOB_URL/<runId>/artifacts) to have them available as a link for later use

  - to archive the full logs (with branch prefix)
    `logparser.archiveLogsWithBranchInfo('consoleText.txt')`
  - to archive the logs from branch2 only
    `logparser.archiveLogsWithBranchInfo('logsBranch2.txt', [filter: ['branch2']])`

Comment: Cool stuff! I was a bit lazy with branch names because I needed something quick for pipeline log parsing for my company. I searched a lot but I couldn't find anything so I just reverse engineered their implementation (which is not open source as far as I know). Let's hope they don't change it for a while :)

Comment: how annoying that the jenkins devs would do a change like https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54304 without the option to turn it off/on when people already rely on it

Comment: I used this tool, it's really amazing! However, you have a typo in your own API:
Your filter function receives branches like this:
`String logsBranch2 = logparser.getLogsWithBranchInfo(filter: ['branch2'])`

And not like this:
`String logsBranch2 = logparser.getLogsWithBranchInfo(filter: 'branch2')`
This caused me pain for like a couple of hours haha

Comment: right, forgot to edit it after the API change. fixed now

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to achieve that, but you need to access the build folder directly (for example using `currentBuild.rawBuild.getLogFile().getParent()`).

- Parse the xml files (or the single `flowNodeStore.xml` file) inside the `workflow` directory:

  - Build a hierarchy of nodes using the `<id>` and `<parentIds>` values.
  - If `<branchName>` is defined associate it to the current node and recursively to all nodes that have this node as parent. If a node has multiple parents assign no branch value to it.
- Read the `log` file as `byte[]`.
- Read each line of `log-index` to find log ranges to assign to each node. The format of a line can be one of the following:

  - `offset nodeId` -> start of new node range, end of the previous (if present).
  - `offset`: end of current node range.
- Convert the byte range back to a utf8 string (`new String(range, "UTF-8")`).

  - You might want to strip away all embedded codes with something like `replaceAll("\u001B.*?\u001B\\[0m", "")`

Comment: if a node has multiple parents it may still belong to a branch if it is in a nested branch (then it belongs to the parent branch) -- except for this little detail this is really helpful, I've been looking for this kind of information for month after workflow-job plugin got rid of the branch information in the logs -- thanks a lot !