# Jenkins Pipeline Parallel step console log format issue

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

We have recently upgraded jenkins to 2.150.3. Since the upgrade. the console logs  of Jenkins parallel steps are less descriptive . It is not showing the parallel stage prefix anymore. It is very complicated to find out which stage on i am currently on.

Is this expected ? Can this be configurable somewhere?

Earlier

```
04:17:02 [junit] [INFO] Scanning for projects...
04:17:04 [junit] [INFO] xxxxx
04:17:04 [junit] [INFO] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
04:17:04 [junit] [INFO] xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Now

```
[junit] 16:03:40  [INFO] Scanning for projects...
16:03:42  [WARNING] 
16:03:42  [WARNING] xxxxx
16:03:42  [WARNING] xxxx
16:03:42  [WARNING] 
16:03:42  [WARNING]
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304403/jenkins-pipeline-how-to-get-logs-from-parallel-builds and/or this issue: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-54304

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you want, but with [Jenkins Blue Ocean](https://jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/) you have a better view on logs of parallel stages.