# How to get console log of current stage?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins pipeline, we can get console log of current build with following -

```
String logData = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(X)
```

Is there a way to get only log of current stage?

Comment: I would love to know this also. but jenkins documentation, maybe just for me, but it sucks so much and their examples are always so bad

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED] you may refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58050883/366749) for a good solution to this, based on more recent Jenkins API's.

[ORIGINAL answer : only works well for non-parallel stages]
The only way I know is to print out (echo) a marker at the beginning and the end of the stage. Then you can have a parsing function that get the whole console log and slices out the stage log between the start and end markers.

For convenience, I recommend creating a custom `stage` DSL command (e.g. `myStage`) that places these markers automatically for you.

Comment: Hm... this is also a good approach but I was looking for some in-build functionality to achieve this. If I don't get it, I'll give a try for this approach. Thanks!

Comment: this works fine if you don't have parallel builds, if you have parallel builds this would not work. unfortunately I can't find a way to make this work for having just the current stage logs