# Saving Jenkins console logs

Tags: arrays, jenkins

We've been using the following method to save Jenkins console logs:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
currentBuild.rawBuild.getLogText().writeLogTo(0, stream)
writeFile file: "archive/${jobName}-log.txt", text: stream.toString()
```

However, I noticed that about half of the logs was getting cut off.

I tried using a different method, and the full log is getting saved correctly:

```
sh""" curl ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/consoleText -o archive/${JOB_NAME}-log.txt """
```

So I started wondering what is wrong with the first method where only 1.2-1.5 MB is getting saved out of 3.5 MB?
I know that this line:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
```

means that the buffer size is initially 32 bytes and it will increase if needed.
What could go wrong here that the buffer supposedly would not increase?

Please help me solve this puzzle. Even thinking out loud in the comments will help.

Comment: The problem may not be the stream itself, but instead one of the operations `getLogText` or `writeLogTo`. But I'm not sure because I was unable to find any documentation specifying the max size these operations can handle. At the same time, logs are expected to be big, so this shouldn't be a problem

Comment: I remember having issues with size limitation of `getLogText()` as well. I finally settled to use https://github.com/gdemengin/pipeline-logparser instead. It has the advantage over the curl method that it also logs (parallel) branch information. You can also filter by branches to be able to store branch logs in separate files. More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58050883/7571258